# Pandas: Most efficient way of change a value in one of the column based on 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas

What will be the best way to perform operations on a column in Pandas DF based on 2 other columns. One of the columns has the value, while other column has the name of column to fill in data.

```
value   B   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
1       C2   0   0   0   0   0
5       C3   0   0   0   0   0
3       C5   0   0   0   0   0
```

Column `value` has the value and column `B` has the details of column to fill in. Hence, the result should look like:

```
value   B   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
1       C2   0   1   0   0   0
5       C3   0   0   5   0   0
3       C5   0   0   0   0   3
```

Any comments on the most efficient way of doing this, or is apply my best friend here?

Answer (score 7):

We do `pivot` then `update`

```
df.update(df.pivot(columns='B',values='value'))
df
   value   B  C1   C2   C3  C4   C5
0      1  C2   0  1.0  0.0   0  0.0
1      5  C3   0  0.0  5.0   0  0.0
2      3  C5   0  0.0  0.0   0  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using [`np.equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) as [`ufunc.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) between the column B and the columns to get boolean array of True where value in B is in the column header. Then use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with the above boolean array created and use the column value to fill.

```
df = df.mask(np.equal.outer(df['B'].to_numpy(), df.columns), df['value'], axis=0)
print (df)
   value   B  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
0      1  C2   0   1   0   0   0
1      5  C3   0   0   5   0   0
2      3  C5   0   0   0   0   3
```